# Is it possible to use C-x C-s for saving in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3, key-bindings

In `Sublime Text 3` is it possible to use `C-x C-s` for saving the file (`save_all`), while keeping `C-s` for search option?

---

`ctrl+x+s` or `ctrl+xctrl+s` did not work on my end.

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+s"], "command": "find_next", "context":
        [{"key": "panel", "operand": "find"}, {"key": "panel_has_focus"}]
},
{ "keys": ["ctrl+x"], "command": "noop" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+x+s"], "command": "save_all" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+x+ctrl+s"], "command": "save_all" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding key chords like this in Sublime requires you to specify both keys individually in the `keys` list (that's why it's a list).

So, what you want is:

```json
{ "keys": ["ctrl+s"], "command": "find_next", "context":
        [{"key": "panel", "operand": "find"}, {"key": "panel_has_focus"}]
},
{ "keys": ["ctrl+x"], "command": "noop" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+x", "ctrl+s"], "command": "save_all" },
```

Note that the binding of <kbd>Ctrl+x</kbd> to `noop` is not needed for this to work, so you can leave that out. However using the same key for both single items and in chords like this may require you to hit the key twice to get Sublime to trigger the command, since it otherwise can't tell without some delay which of the bindings you intended.

Comment: Assigning noop to Ctrl-X would also kill the shortcut for Cut.

Comment: Indeed; I left it in there in @alper was doing it on purpose and not as a part of this binding (since the other bindings are nonstandard). Without it you need to hit the key twice to cut (in ST~~4~~ anyway; I didn't re-verify in ST3) so if you want to use that in the chord you probably want to rebind it to something else anyway.

Comment: @MattDMo I am using `Ctrl-W` for cut. I get use to emacs's keybindings (https://github.com/leeorengel/my-emacs-keybindings#selectioncopypaste) I wish I was able to set all default keybindings match with emacs

Comment: @alper I found [`Emacs Pro Essentials`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Emacs%20Pro%20Essentials) in Package Control that claims to have a whole bunch of Emacs key bindings, perhaps that might help? Good old **E**scape-**M**eta-**A**lt-**C**ontrol-**S**hift. 'Twas my favorite editor for a while, until I started working on systems that didn't have it installed and was forced to the evil world of vim :)

Comment: I already got `Emacs Pro Essentials` but seems like they didn't cover `C-x C-s` and more other stuff :-(  I have tried to use vim but I wasn't able to use it. It was like when you have learned playing tennis with your right hand but now you have to switch to playing with your left hand, you know what to do but you cannot do it properly.